# Typo3 9.5: Language Fallback does not work with gridelements

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-gridelements

I have the following problem:
The language fallbacks do not work for the content of the grid element. The grid element itself (e.g. the headline of it) works as a fallback, but the content is not displayed.
Even if I don't translate the page at all and the complete page content falls back to the fallback (then only menu links and hardcoded translations), the problem occurs.

So far I have been able to find little (almost nothing, to be precise) about the problem and would be pleased if someone could give me a push in the right direction.

YAML-Config:

```
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: 1
    base: en/
    typo3Language: en
    locale: en_GB.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-EN
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: gb
  -
    title: Nederlands
    enabled: true
    languageId: 2
    base: nl/
    typo3Language: nl
    locale: nl_NL.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: nl
    navigationTitle: Nederlands
    hreflang: nl-NL
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '1,0'
    flag: nl
  -
    title: Polskie
    enabled: true
    languageId: 3
    base: pl/
    typo3Language: pl
    locale: pl_PL.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: pl
    navigationTitle: Polskie
    hreflang: pl-PL
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '1,0'
    flag: pl
```

Config:

```
config {
        colCount = 2
        rowCount = 1
        rows {
            1 {
                columns {
                    1 {
                        name = Left
                        colPos = 20
                        allowed {
                            CType = shortcut,textmedia,iconlist,link-list-teaser,form_formframework
                        }
                    }
                    2 {
                        name = Right
                        colPos = 21
                        allowed {
                            CType = shortcut,textmedia,iconlist,link-list-teaser,form_formframework
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Setup:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    grid-50-50 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    grid-50-50 {
        cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
        cObject {
            partialRootPaths < lib.contentElement.partialRootPaths
            templateRootPaths < lib.contentElement.templateRootPaths
            layoutRootPaths < lib.contentElement.layoutRootPaths

            file = EXT:XXX/Resources/Private/Content/Gridelements/grid-50-50/Template.html
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

    <f:layout name="Gridelements"/>

    <f:section name="Main">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns small-12 tablet-6">{data.tx_gridelements_view_column_20 -> f:format.raw()}</div>
            <div class="columns small-12 tablet-6">{data.tx_gridelements_view_column_21 -> f:format.raw()}</div>
        </div>
    </f:section>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check `\GridElementsTeam\Gridelements\Plugin\Gridelements::getChildren` and make a debug output of $element there?

Usually it should be the UID of the parent container holding the child elements.
Within the method, the child language is determined with `$this->languageAspect->getContentId()`, so actually the fallback value should be considered correctly.

To check that, make a debug output of getContentId() too.

My current guess is, that either the container ID itself might be wrong or the languageAspect is missing the fallback information.

If they contain the wrong values, please file a bug report at https://gitlab.com/coderscare/gridelements/-/issues

Comment: Thanks for the push :-)

I tracked down the problem to the following method:
\GridElementsTeam\Gridelements\Plugin\LayoutSetup::loadLayoutSetup

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->getPagesTSconfig() doesn't contain any data für gridelements.
For some other extensions (tx_news for example) there is data, so i think i maybe have a misconfiguration somewhere... but didn't found it yet.
Language Config is just standard in this project... no fancy stuff...